# CSR: ScriptLink/Custom Action CDN Libraries load after JSLinked files are loaded

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, custom-actions, client-side-rendering, scriptlink

I am almost to 2.0 with the generic iCSR support library.

Having some issues with deployment:

- Adding the library as SiteCollection ScriptLink/Custom action loads it **before** msajaxbundle where `Type.registerNamespace` is defined

The workaround is to put a copy of msajaxbundle in the style library, and load it as (another) Custom Action:

[image]

I first tried the absolute CDN url for msajaxbundle but then (for me) unwanted behaviour happens.

So I have these CustomActions:

[image]

The absolute URL **is** loaded, but only way down after many scripts have loaded:

[image]

That means: **Custom Action files with external URLs are loaded AFTER JSLinks**

And that really s*ks because I would like to have one (CDN) iCSR library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Earlier it was not possible to inject scripts from CDN to ScriptLink location, you had to use ScriptBlock location to do that. I did some tests and now it is possible, at least in o365! So I updated the [Chrome SP Editor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-sp-editor/ecblfcmjnbbgaojblcpmjoamegpbodhd) chrome extension to support this too. So now, all injections will respect the sequence and will load in correct order.